# Problem while getting application lightning event in salesforce lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, js-controller

I am not able to get the reference to an application level Lightning Event inside an Lightning component.

I have defined an application level event named 'MemberEvent' and I have registered it in component UI like this,

```
<aura:registerEvent name="MemberEvent" type="c:MemberEvent"/>
```

Now inside an action of js controller, I am trying to call this event like,

```
var mEvent = $A.get("e.c:MemberEvent");
```

But in **mEvent** is undefined and I am not able to set the parameter. This is a general format to get an event but I am not able to understand why I am not getting this reference. Please help me here if I am missing any of the steps or check to invoke an event.

Thanks

Comment: Have you given name in handler for the  application event?. It wont work if you have given name when declaring handler for application events?

Comment: Thanks @RedDevil,  Yes I am giving the name in handler as well like this
    <aura:handler event="c:MemberEvent" action="{!c.eventHandler}"/>
The problem is that I am not even able to setParams for the event. The error is like **Cannot read property 'setParams' of undefined**

Comment: Welcome to SFSC, Please read [ask] and add your complete component code

Answer (score 2):

Never mind, I have fixed my problem. I was not getting the reference because The event was application and its access was Global but the components were not and The code was from an unmanaged package.

So my observations are that the application level event should be global and all the implementing component should also be global if you want to access it from a package.